# Download software failed after system upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I have got the following code

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Which, after the download was completed, entered into a page that asks for configuration settings
when I worked on a terminal , I was working with another software. I created a button that made the terminal hang up.

I closed the terminal and re-entered the code and made the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Then I stopped it.

Now I use Ubuntu software to install another package. But it not install anything and report this error:

> authentication is required to install, update, or remove packages
>
> incorrect permissions on / usr / lib / policykit-1 /
>   polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)

I can't open the file to the path.

Also synaptic is disabled.

I have a whole set of software that I can not install over again on Ubuntu and change Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code it gives you to run manually AKA `sudo dpkg --configure -a` character for character.

Then run `sudo apt-get update`.

This is what I did for the exact same problem and error message and it worked.